# Manipulating an Integer Object Without creating a new Instance?

Tags: java, integer, mutability

I have:

```
// lets call this Integer reference ABC101
Integer i = new Integer(5);

//j points to i so j has the reference ABC101
Integer j = i;

//creates a new Integer instance for j?
j++;
//I want j++ to edit and return ABC101
System.out.println(i); // 5 not 6
```

So my goal is to manipulate I via a different Object with the same reference without switching references. And no don't say, "Why don't you just use ints or why don't you just mess with I directly". That isn't the purpose of this exercise. There is always easier ways to do things, but this is what I'm supposed to be dealing with. Last question... does that mean Integer objects are immutable?

Comment: Yes, `Integer` classes are immutable in Java.

Comment: @ervinszilagyi so that means it is not possible?

Comment: Or more correctly, Integer _objects_ are immutable.  It is not possible to change them once created.

Comment: @gmanrocks: You can use the internal `AtomicInteger` which _is_ mutable; or create your own wrapper class: `class MyInt { int value; }` (please make this better...) to achieve this.

Comment: You can manipulate (cached) `Integer`s through reflection, as shown [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5/28818#28818). Obviously, you _shouldn't_ be doing that in any production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, all primitives (int, boolean, double etc.) and their respective Wrapper classes are immutable.

It is not possible to use the postincrement operator `j++` to change the value of i.
This is because `j++` translates to `j = j + 1` and the assignment operator `=` means that i and j no longer refer to the same object.

What you could do is either use an array of int (or Integer, whatever you prefer). Your code would then look like this

```java
int i[] = {5};

int j[] = i;

j[0]++;
System.out.println(i[0]); // prints 6
```

This is however not recommended. In my opinion you should use your own wrappe class for int that could look like this

```java
public class MutableInt

private int i;
public MutableInt(int i) {
  set(i);
}

public int get() {
  return i;
}

public void set(int i) {
  this.i = i;
}

public void increment() {
  i++;
}

// more stuff if you want to
```

Be aware that you won't be able to use autoboxing this way and that there is no Cache like for `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: AtomicInteger is specifically for concurrency in mind, which makes it a bit slower even though you don't need it

Comment: Thank you. Is there some way to force an autobox? Like basically say, I want this particular class (In this case a newly created Integer wrapper) to autobox to int when the JVM deems it possible.

Comment: And also why does the operation work and change it using an array. Oh nvm cause you're doing j[0] = j[0] + 1; which stores it back in the same location. So in essence that means you're manually creating your own reference system like the JVM has? A very basic one of course...? Am I following that correctly?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to force the JVM to Autobox your own class. The one with the array works because you are essentaily making use of the array as a wrapper for a mutable value

Comment: Hi, you wrote "...use an array of int... This is however not recommended". Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Because the intention of an array of integer is that you have some amount of integers in a data structure so you can do something with them, e.g. loop through them. Using an integer array to have a mutable int just abuses the fact that arrays are mutable. If your intention is to have a mutable int, use a mutable int, not something else that can be abused to be one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using AtomicInteger

```
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(5);
    AtomicInteger j = i;
    j.addAndGet(1);
    System.out.println(i); //6
    System.out.println(j); //6
```